# Infinite Scroll in angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, infinite-scroll

I am trying to use infinite scroll in a angular UI modal and the modal is defined in ng-template as shown below

```
                   <script type="text/ng-template" id="someID" >
  <div infinite-scroll="loadMoreEmployees()" infinite-scroll-distance="1">
            <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="vertical-margin row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="help-block">Departments assign</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 simple-data-table-content">
                <table data-ng-if="vm.employees!=null || vm.employees.length!=0" class="table table-condensed text-center clear-bottom">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee No</th>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th data-ng-repeat="DeptType in vm.DeptTypes track by $index">{{DeptType.name}}</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-ng-if="vm.employees==null || vm.employees.length==0"><td colspan="{{vm.DeptTypes.length + 4}}"></td></tr>

                        <tr data-ng-repeat="employee in vm.employees | limitTo:vm.loadEmployeeLimitCount" data-ng-if="vm.employees!=null && vm.employees.length > 0">
                            <td class="">{{employee.employeeNumber}}</td>
                            <td class="">{{employee.name}}</td>
                            <td class="">{{employee.email}}</td>
                            <td class="" data-ng-repeat="DeptType in vm.DeptTypes">
                                <input type="text" only-digits data-ng-model="employee.DeptSummary[DeptType.id]" style="width:50px;" min="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But infinite scroll as does not respond to scroll action, please point out where I am wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker or the implementation of `infiniteScroll` directive?

Comment: @Saad the infinite scroll code is used from here 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BinaryMuse/ngInfiniteScroll/1.0.0/build/ng-infinite-scroll.js

Comment: First make sure, `loadMoreEmployees()` is getting called or not when infinite-scroll condition satisfies. If `loadMoreEmployees()` gets called, remember to update `$scope.vm.loadEmployeeLimitCount`. If you won't update, scrolling won't show loaded employees.

Comment: @Saad yes I am updating the count by 50 the function is called on modal loading but no effect while scrolling, I think the scroll bar must be of $window, not modal. I am working on css to inherit scroll bar of parent window not modal's..

Comment: @Sadd Hi I have applied css as 'position:initial' to .modal  class which is triggering scroll bar actions and working fine, does it inherit parent scroll bar now....? I think it does..

Comment: The problem with 'position:initial' is that `initial` still not supported by IE. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp).  So you might want to use something else.